# API: GET-request with user_id or name+region

Tags: rest, api, express, request

In my API I have a GET /users/ which gets me an array of all documents in users-collection.
And I have a GET /users/:user_id which gets me a user.
I also want to have a GET /users/name.region which gets me one user.
Is this possible?

Do I have to use query params like GET /users/name="Joe"&region="US"? 
How would I have to implement this? In another endpoints or is there a way of checking if its either a user_id or the combination of name and region?

Something like this?

```
if !req.params{
model.find({"name":query.params.name, "region": query.params.region})}
else
model.find({"user_id": req.params.user_id})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually having something different than `GET users/:id` will break most popular REST guides like [Google's Resource Name specs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/resource_names).

What would be much better to do is have a `GET users/search` end-point which accepts various query parameters, such as `name` and `region` and give the desired query of users.

Answer (score 0):

*Maybe you can do it with the same route...*

**An exemple**

```
const givenId = req.params.user_id;
const parts   = givenId.split('.');

if (parts.length === 2) {
    const name   = parts[0];
    const region = parts[1];
} else { 
    const userId = givenId;
}
```